# YouTube Java API problems

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

I'm trying to get a list of videos by a certain user using the YouTube Java GData library/API.

However, when I try to create a service by using `YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("Cyphon-MyCampusPulse-1", YOUTUBE_API_KEY);`, I get the following runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
at scrapers.YouTubePulseScraper.<init>(YouTubePulseScraper.java:37)
at scrapers.YouTubePulseScraper.main(YouTubePulseScraper.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 2 more
```

I'm not sure how the exception relates to what I'm doing. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the JavaMail jar to your classpath, which contains javax.mail.MessagingException. You can get it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html

Edit: 
Extracted from the documentation:

> The GData Java Client Library has the
>   following external dependencies. The
>   following sections will describe how
>   to install these dependencies on your
>   favorite operating system (or the OS
>   that you're stuck with at work).
>
> - JDK (Java Development Kit) version 1.5+
> - Apache Ant version 1.7+
> - mail.jar in Sun's JavaMail API 1.4+
> - activation.jar in Sun's JavaBeansActivationFramewrok. This is
>     only required for media specific APIs
>     including Document List Data API,
>     Picasa Web Album API, and YouTube Data
>     API.
> - servlet.jar in Sun's Servlet API version 2.3+. This is required only if
>     executing code samples in
>     'sample.authsub' or
>     'sample.gbase.recipe' packages.
>
> A few of the .jar dependencies are
>   only required for specific samples,
>   but to avoid build errors, it's best
>   just to get everything. Choose your
>   operating system of choice to
>   continue:
>   [Windows](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#windows),
>   [Mac OS
>   X](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#mac),
>   or
>   [Linux](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#linux).

I've added this since if you're missing one dependency you might be missing others, so you should double check you have everything.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed this dependency list. I was really confused as to why Mail was being used, but I guess that's not my concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), which is available from [Maven Repository](https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```